# REST listdata.svc call to another site in collection doesn't return people picker values

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery, people-picker, rest

I have two sites on the same collection. There is a people picker field on my list in site2. I am in Sharepoint 2010.

mysharepointsite/site1
mysharepointsite/site2

I am using the Sharepoint REST API to get list data from site2 (calling from site1). All other fields except my people picker are being returned. I also tried this with the asmx web services via the SPServices library, same result. Is this by design, maybe a limitation related to passing people picker data between two sites? I have some workarounds, but this is just bugging me now.

```
$.ajax({
    url: stageGateBaseURL + "listdata.svc/Investment",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        debugger
        $.each(response.d.results, function(key, value) {  

             var projectManager = value.ProjectManager; //people picker is not returned in the results.

        });
    },
    error: function(response){
        debugger
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  order to retrieve User field details, `$expand` OData query option needs to be applied to query.

For example, the following query returns `Title` along with projected* `Name` property of `CreatedBy` user field  from `Pages` library:

```
http://intranet.contoso.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Pages?$select=Title,CreatedBy/Name&$expand=CreatedBy
```

> *Projected* fields are retrieved by joining lists, in this case `Pages` 
>   and `User Information` lists

### Example

```
var svcUrl = 'http://intranet.contoso.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/';
$.ajax({
    url: svcUrl + "Pages?$select=Title,CreatedBy/Name&$expand=CreatedBy",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response.d.results[0].CreatedBy.Name); //print CreatedBy Name 
    },
    error: function(response){
        console(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```